# Template of image, one left; two right

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikitext

I'm sorry for my terrible English, - I speak Dutch - but you'll probably understand me.

I don't know if there exist templates in HTML, but I use [Wikia](http://wikia.com), I have a Wiki by my own. I am not an expert in HTML, but I'm not a beginner. If you can put the code in Wiki language, I'm very thankfull. But if it exist, it may also be in HTML code.

Is there a code to put in a template, and if you put the template on your page en you add the file parameters, that the first file is aligned right, the second left, the third right, the fourth left... 
And I know this is easy to do, but I want it to put the template apart on the page; to put between text, so I can't put it in one template.

It may be hard to understand wat I said if you don't know Wiki language, so I'm very sorry.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to link images into Wiki pages an align them, left, right, etc.

If so, this is quite easy:

```
[[File:Yourfile.svg|right|thumb|'tis Wiki mojo!]]
```

More examples are available in the [MediaWiki manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages#Horizontal_alignment).